# Word2Vec: Identifying many-to-one relationships between words

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec, ai, vector-space-models

Standard introductory examples in Word2Vec, like `king - queen = man - woman` and `tokyo - japan = london - uk`, involve one-to-one relationships between words: Tokyo is the *exclusive* capital of Japan.

More generally, we might want to test for many-to-one relationships: e.g. we might want to ask if Kyoto is a *city* in Japan. I presume we are still interested in vectors of the form `kyoto - japan`, `houston - us`, etc., but these vectors are no longer *equal*.

Do these "relationship vectors" form a particularly interesting vector space? Do they sample some known distribution? How can I check a many-to-one relationship from the word embeddings?

Answer (score 1):

Those vector relations are not exact. Rest assured that `king - queen ≠ man - woman`. What we do is finding the closest vectors to the result of `king - man + woman`. One of the closest vectors is `queen`.

Nevertheless, when we try the "parallelogram approach" to verify word relations, in most cases, the closest vector is the original one. The fact that we disregard the original word as a sensible result is due to the original implementation of word2vec, as shown in the study [*Fair is Better than Sensational:
Man is to Doctor as Woman is to Doctor*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09866). This implementation quirk is actually one of the sources of gender bias attributed to word embeddings.

There are other articles studying the limitations of the analogies based on word embeddings, like [this](https://cocosci.princeton.edu/papers/peterson_parallelograms.pdf) and [this](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/S17-1017.pdf).

That being said, there are also studies of the relationships that can be found in word representation spaces, like [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04416), which studies different types of relationships, e.g.  class-inclussion, part-whole, attributes, etc. You may find the main figure of the article interesting:

[image]